# How to remove a subString using Last index in Java Script?

Tags: javascript

My String is

```
var str = "{ aaaa} bbb} ccc ] } ddd } eeee"
```

I want newString as by using last occurance of `}`

```
var newString = "{ aaaa} bbb} ccc ] } ddd }"
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```js
var s = '{ aaaa} bbb} ccc ] } ddd } eeee';
alert( s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('}')+1));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var newString = str.replace(/ \w+$/, '');
```

Comment: @Group : he did exactly what you asked for... you don't believe,  here comes the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8esw7t1L/

Comment: @Oxi event though it works for the given string, he asked for the last occurence of {, not for the last "space + chars" sequence

Comment: @JeromeWAGNER : i get it now, thanks.  small correction in your comment, it is "last occurence of }"  NOT "last occurence of {"  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var newString = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf('}')+1)
```